# <ion-item> keeps same parameters when deleted

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using ionic framework to do an app for school. The app is for requests to restaurants.

I have a modal that shows my requests, listing from localstorage the items that I requested.

The problem is, when I delete the bottom item first, it does correctly, removing the price that is supposed to. *But* if I remove the top item first, then the second item comes with the parameters of the first one:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="entradasPedido in entradasPedidos track by $index" class="item item-thumbnail-left ">
  <img src="{{entradasPedido.url}}">
  <h2>{{entradasPedido.name}}</h2>
  <p>Esta entrada fica por {{entradasPedido.price}} €</p>
  <span class="badge badge-assertive">{{entradasPedido.quantidade}} und.</span>
  <ion-option-button class="button-dark"
    ng-click="showPopupEditEntradas($index, {{entradasPedido.id}}, {{entradasPedido.quantidade}})">
  Alterar</ion-option-button>
  <ion-option-button class="button-assertive"
     ng-click="showPopupApagarEntradas($index, {{entradasPedido.price}}, {{entradasPedido.quantidade}})">
    Apagar</ion-option-button>
</ion-item>
```

```
$scope.showPopupApagarEntradas = function(id, price, quant) {
  var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
    title: 'Tem a certeza que quer remover?',
    template: 'Pode adicionar novamente se desejar.'
  });
  confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
    if(res) {
      StorageServiceEntradas.remove(id);
      var total = price * quant;
      var total1 = parseFloat($localstorage.get('preco_final')) - parseFloat(total);
      console.log($localstorage.get('preco_final') + " - " + total + " = " + total1);

      $localstorage.set('preco_final', total1.toFixed(2));
      $scope.reloadDataModal();
    } else {
      console.log('You are not sure');
    }
    //confirmPopup.close();
  });
};
```

Image with the example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using the variable `$index` of:

```
ng-repeat="entradasPedido in entradasPedidos track by $index
```

as the `id` parameter of the function:

```
function showPopupApagarEntradas(id, price, quant)
```

From [ngRepeat official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat]), `$index` represents the:

> iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1)

It's is in no way linked to the identifier of the items contained in `StorageServiceEntradas`. It seems that you would have to call `showPopupApagarEntradas(entradasPedido.id, etc.)`.